# How to drag only when the text appears

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I saw this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWGXRQ) where a whole item is draggable. I tried to change dragging to apply only when user hover and click on the text only, but it didn't work:

Does someone know how to do this?

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
  update: ..
},
  stop: ..
},
  handle: '.handle'
};
```

here my Whole Code is.

```js
<ul class="list logList">
  <li ng-repeat="entry in sortingLog track by $index" class="logItem">
    <span class="handle"> {{entry}} </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
var myapp = angular.module('sortableApp', ['ui.sortable']);


myapp.controller('sortableController', function ($scope) {
  var tmpList = [];
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    tmpList.push({
      text: 'Item ' + i,
      value: i
    });
  }
  
  $scope.list = tmpList;
  
  
  $scope.sortingLog = [];
  
  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    update: function(e, ui) {
      var logEntry = tmpList.map(function(i){
        return i.value;
      }).join(', ');
      $scope.sortingLog.push('Update: ' + logEntry);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      // this callback has the changed model
      var logEntry = tmpList.map(function(i){
        return i.value;
      }).join(', ');
      $scope.sortingLog.push('Stop: ' + logEntry);
    },
    handle: '.handle'
  };
});
```

```css
.list {
 list-style: none outside none;
 margin: 10px 0 30px;
}

.item {
 width: 200px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 margin: 5px 0;
 border: 2px solid #444;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #EA8A8A;

 font-size: 1.1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: move;
}


/***  Extra ***/

body {
 font-family: Verdana, 'Trebuchet ms', Tahoma;
}

.logList {
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 250px;
 min-height: 200px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 border: 5px solid #000;
 border-radius: 15px;
}

.logList:before {
 content: 'log';
 padding: 0 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -1.1em;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

.container {
 width: 600px;
 margin: auto;
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sortableApp" ng-controller="sortableController" class="container">
  <h2>ui.sortable single minified cdn file</h2>

  <div class="floatleft">
    <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list" class="list">
      <li ng-repeat="item in list" class="item">
        {{item.text}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="floatleft" style="margin-left: 20px;">
    <ul class="list logList">
      <li ng-repeat="entry in sortingLog track by $index" class="logItem">
        <span class="handle"> {{entry}} </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@1,jquery.ui@1.10%28jquery.ui.core.min.js+jquery.ui.widget.min.js+jquery.ui.mouse.min.js+jquery.ui.sortable.min.js%29,angularjs@1.2,angular.ui-sortable"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: example not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `handle`gets a selector relative to the `<li>` and not to the `<ul>`

as seen in this example:

http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/PGRoRY

Answer (score 0):

hi this is an example of how it's done with jquery

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
<body>
<style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style> 
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>


</body>
```